# finding the maximum of a second derivative of a function given its differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Say I have $u(x)$ satisfying $\frac{d}{dx}(a(x)u'(x)) = 0$ with $u(0) = 0$ and $u(l) = 1$.

Is there any way to find the maximum of $u''$, for example, without having to solve for the function $u$ from the above differential equation? I am looking for a result of the form $||u''(x)||_{\infty} \le C||a(x)||_{\infty}$. Let's say that $a(x)$ is a complicated function so that finding $u$ explicitly is cumbersome...

I've seen some results in PDEs involving the maximum of the nonhomogeneous term but I don't recall anything similar to the above.

Comment: This is an ODE, not a PDE, actually.

Answer (score 1):

we have $$(au')' = 0 \to au' = B \to u(x) = \frac{\int_0^x \frac 1 a \,dx}{\int_0^l \frac 1a \, dx}, u' = \frac 1{a  \int_0^l \frac 1a \, dx}  $$

we also have 
$$au'' + a'u' = 0,\,  au'''+2a'u'' +a''u' = 0 $$
at a local maximum $M$ of $$u'', u''' = 0 \text{ so that } 2a'M + a''u' = 0 \to M = -\frac{a''u'}{2a'}.$$ that is $$M = -\frac{a''}{2a\, a' \,\int_0^l \frac 1a \, dx }.$$

Comment: Nice solution; well done.  The OP requested, however, that the approach prohibit explicitly finding $u$.  It is unclear whether that is a tractable request.

Comment: @Dr.MV, thanks. this is all i could come up with. i will be happy to see how it can be down without much information about $a.$

Comment: Your approach is the one that I would have taken - direct and to the point.  I am not sure how to provide a bound for $M$ if $u$ is not explicitly found.  We know that $M=-\frac{a''u'}{2a'}$, but we don't know a priori as to the bounds for $u'$ except that it is some constant $B$ divided by $a$.  So if we know properties of $a$, then perhaps we could pursue this line of attack.  Thoughts?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the suggestions! Yes Dr MV's right. Finding $u$ explicitly is computationally expensive, much so finding $u'$. The above looks promising only if I had a bound on $u'$.

Comment: But also, won't the initial conditions have an impact on the outcome?

Comment: @user157279,  boundary/initial conditions have been incorporated in finding $u,u'.$ once you know what $a$ is every thing else is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

We have that $a'u'+au''=0$ , so $u''=-\frac{a'u'}{a}$. So $\|u''\|_\infty=\|\frac{a'u'}{a}\|_{\infty}\le\|u'\|_{\infty}\|\frac{a'}{a}\|_\infty$. We will need some assumptions on $a$ in order to obtain an $L^\infty$ upper bound on $u'$. Differentiating our equation we get 
$$u'''a+u''a'+a''u'+a'u''=u'''a+2a'u''+a''u=0$$
i.e.,
$$\frac{d}{dx}(au'')=-\frac{d}{dx}(a'u'),$$ if $u,a$ are regular enough this is the same as $-\frac{d}{dx}(au'')=f(x)$, for some some $f$ of sufficient regularity (note we will be working with weak solutions so I will leave the regularity assumptions to you).

In the more general elliptic setting, if we have $$-\nabla\cdot(A\nabla u)=0,$$ the De Giorgi Nash Moser theorem: https://www.ma.utexas.edu/mediawiki/index.php/De_Giorgi-Nash-Moser_theorem, gives us holder regularity of $u$, this can of course be extended to give us Holder regularity of $\partial_{x_i}u$, if we have sufficient regularity of $A$ such that we can write $$-\nabla\cdot(A\nabla \partial_{x_i}u)=0,$$
for each $i=1,\ldots,n$.
This can also be extended to the case of a non homogeneous right hand side (i.e., our case).

So it results in something like
$$\|u'\|_{C^\alpha}\le C(\|u'\|_{L^2}+\|f\|_{L^2})$$
and by elliptic regularity, considering our original equation, we can find an upper bound for $\|u'\|_{L^2}$.

Note that I am giving a very rough Idea as to how you can find such a bound, because the full details would likely be very lengthy.